# Using shell script to replace the string in file with another string having special character

Tags: linux, sed

I try to  replace string in the following file with another string which is having  special character like(=,",-) .

This is service file , i need to  customize and add Naming Service to this file restart again

```
#!/bin/bash

. /etc/init.d/functions

PIDFILE=/var/run/Naming_Service.pid

PORT=

OPTIONS="-p ${PIDFILE}"

RETVAL=0

prog="Naming_Service"

    start() {
        echo -n $"Starting $prog: "
    
        if [ $UID -ne 0 ]; then
    
            RETVAL=1
    
            failure
    
        else
    
            setsid /usr/local/bin/Naming_Service ${OPTIONS} &
    
            RETVAL=$?
    
    
        fi
    
        echo 
    
        return $RETVAL
    
    }
```

In this file I want to  replace first occurrence of

> OPTIONS="-p ${PIDFILE}"

replace with

> OPTIONS_1234="-p ${PIDFILE_1234} -ORBEndpoint iiop://10.12.23.34:1234"
>
> OPTIONS_1235="-p ${PIDFILE_1235} -ORBEndpoint iiop://10.12.23.34:1235"
>
> OPTIONS_1236="-p ${PIDFILE_1236} -ORBEndpoint iiop://10.12.23.34:1236"

I wrote one shell script file with sed command , I have issues with special symbols.
can you please give solution for this

```
PORT_NS=13021

PIDFILE=/home/vagrant/Naming_Service_${PORT_NS}.pid

PIDFILE_13016=/home/vagrant/Naming_Service_${PORT_NS}.pid

ORIGINAL="OPTIONS="-p ${PIDFILE}""

REPLACE="OPTIONS_13016="-p ${PIDFILE_13016} -ORBEndpoint iiop://172.31.153.56:13016""

sed -i "0,/$ORIGINAL/s//$REPLACE/" "tao"
```

Comment: Show us your "_shell script file with sed command_".

Comment: I made it basic way,  like i wrote following cmd in file                                                                                          sed -i '0,/$ORIGINAL/$REPLACE' filename

Comment: "issues with special symbols" ? Hmm, I wish you had written which special symbols are causing you issues, then maybe I/we could help. But I can't spend time guessing which. (Please update your Q with the stuff that is NOT working, including a (very) small sample of "special symbols" AND your required output after processing them. OK? ;-) ).  Good luck.

Comment: first occurrence of
OPTIONS="-p ${PIDFILE}"
replace with
OPTIONS_1234="-p ${PIDFILE_1234} -ORBEndpoint iiop://10.12.23.34:1234"

OPTIONS_1235="-p ${PIDFILE_1235} -ORBEndpoint iiop://10.12.23.34:1235"

OPTIONS_1236="-p ${PIDFILE_1236} -ORBEndpoint iiop://10.12.23.34:1236"                 this is what i'm looking for

Comment: PORT_NS=13021

PIDFILE=/home/vagrant/Naming_Service_${PORT_NS}.pid
echo $PIDFILE

ORIGINAL="OPTIONS="-p ${PIDFILE}""
REPLACE="OPTIONS_13016="-p ${PIDFILE_13016} -ORBEndpoint iiop://172.31.153.56:13016""
echo $ORIGINAL
sed -i "0,/$ORIGINAL/s//$REPLACE/" "tao"

Comment: [edit] your question with that information please.

Comment: You should edit your question insteado of open a new one with same purpose!

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
sed '0,/\PIDFILE=\/var\/run\/Naming_Service.pid/ s//\PIDFILE_1234=\/var\/run\/Naming_Service_1234.pid\n\PIDFILE_1235=\/var\/run\/Naming_Service_1235.pid\n\PIDFILE_1236=\/var\/run\/Naming_Service_1236.pid\n /' script > newscript
sed '0,/\OPTIONS="-p ${PIDFILE}"/ s//\OPTIONS_1234="-p ${PIDFILE_1234} -ORBEndpoint iiop:\/\/10.12.23.34:1234"\n\OPTIONS_1235="-p ${PIDFILE_1235} -ORBEndpoint iiop:\/\/10.12.23.34:1235"\n\OPTIONS_1236="-p ${PIDFILE_1236} -ORBEndpoint iiop:\/\/10.12.23.34:1236"\n /' newscript > script
```

Should output what you need.

Comment: Its removing my complete file and showing error like                                                
addns.sh: 8: addns.sh: sed0,/\PIDFILE=\/var\/run\/Naming_Service.pid/s//\PIDFILE_1234=\/var\/run\/Naming_Service_1234.pid\n
\PIDFILE_1235=\/var\/run\/Naming_Service_1235.pid\n
\PIDFILE_1236=\/var\/run\/Naming_Service_1236.pid\n /: not found
sed: -e expression #1, char 107: unterminated `s' command

Comment: really strange, in my computer work flawless. Did you copy and paste ?

Comment: Its working for me .i made small mistake .  but end user not able to provide like this pattren ,                                          sed '0,/\PIDFILE=\/var\/run\/Naming_Service.pid/ s//\PIDFILE_1234=\/var\/run\/Naming_Service_1234.pid\n /' script > newscript
sed '0,/\OPTIONS="-p ${PIDFILE}"/ s//\OPTIONS_1234="-p ${PIDFILE_1234} -ORBEndpoint iiop:\/\/10.12.23.34:1234"\n /' newscript > script                                                                                                            so I expecting  some pattern  to achieve this