# How to make shell script to make changes by end user easily

Tags: linux, awk, sed

This is requirement i want to replace the following  string

```
OPTIONS="-p ${PIDFILE}"
```

with

```
OPTIONS_1234="-p ${PIDFILE_1234} -ORBEndpoint iiop://10.12.23.34:1234"

OPTIONS_1235="-p ${PIDFILE_1235} -ORBEndpoint iiop://10.12.23.34:1235"

OPTIONS_1236="-p ${PIDFILE_1236} -ORBEndpoint iiop://10.12.23.34:1236"
```

for this i'm following script to work around

```
sed '0,/\PIDFILE=\/var\/run\/Naming_Service.pid/s//\PIDFILE_13021=\/var\/run\/Naming_Service_13021.pid\n\PIDFILE_13022=\/var\/run\/Naming_Service_13022.pid\n\PIDFILE_13023=\/var\/run\/Naming_Service_13023.pid\n /' tao > tao_pid
sed '0,/\OPTIONS="-p ${PIDFILE}"/ s//\OPTIONS_13021="-p ${PIDFILE_13021} -ORBEndpoint iiop:\/\/10.12.23.34:13021"\n\OPTIONS_13022="-p ${PIDFILE_13022} -ORBEndpoint iiop:\/\/10.12.23.34:13022"\n\OPTIONS_13023="-p ${PIDFILE_13023} -ORBEndpoint iiop:\/\/10.12.23.34:13023"\n /' script > new_script
```

But if end user want to  add one more like

```
OPTIONS_1236="-p ${PIDFILE_1236} -ORBEndpoint iiop://10.12.23.34:1237"
```

it difficult to maintain special characters and all. 
anybody can suggest best optimized way to do that should  be easy for end user

Comment: Can you please share the content of input file and expected output?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using shell script to replace the string in file with another string having special character](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40601465/using-shell-script-to-replace-the-string-in-file-with-another-string-having-spec)

Answer (score 1):

You can set a variable with desired value and inject it in a sed command:

```
num=1234;
sed 's~^\(OPTIONS\)="\(-p \${PIDFILE\)}~\1'"_$num"'="\2'"_$num"'} -ORBEndpoint iiop://10.12.23.34:'"$num"'~' <<< 'OPTIONS="-p ${PIDFILE}"'
```

**output:**:

```
OPTIONS_1234="-p ${PIDFILE_1234} -ORBEndpoint iiop://10.12.23.34:1234"
```

Using a loop:

```
for num in 1234 1235 1236; do
    sed 's~^\(OPTIONS\)="\(-p \${PIDFILE\)}~\1'"_$num"'="\2'"_$num"'} -ORBEndpoint iiop://10.12.23.34:'"$num"'~' <<< 'OPTIONS="-p ${PIDFILE}"'
done
```

**output:**

```
OPTIONS_1234="-p ${PIDFILE_1234} -ORBEndpoint iiop://10.12.23.34:1234"
OPTIONS_1235="-p ${PIDFILE_1235} -ORBEndpoint iiop://10.12.23.34:1235"
OPTIONS_1236="-p ${PIDFILE_1236} -ORBEndpoint iiop://10.12.23.34:1236"
```